# Raiserror in procedure (SQL Server 2014) does not catch client side(c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, raiseerror

Stored procedure Catch block code.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTError]      
(

)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

      BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 5/0
      END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT

           SELECT @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER() 

           RAISERROR
        (N'The error code is: %d',
             16, -- Severity.
              1, -- State.
             @ErrorNumber,     
             '');
END CATCH
END
```

The above stored procedure throw and show error when runs using SSMS.

.Net Client code only exception portion.

```
    catch (SqlException ex)
            {      
                string msg = string.Format("Error number: {0} / Message: {1}", ex.Number, ex.Message);
            }
```

When application called stored procedure it does not catch in exception block.

Any kind of hint or idea would help me.

Comment: Hi Morshed! Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (SqlException ex)
        {      
            string msg = string.Format("Error number: {0} / Message: {1}", ex.Number, ex.Message);
        }
```

What are you expecting to happen, even if this catch-block was entered? A string variable would get a value which is gone the next micro second...

Anyway: Whenever you deal with specialised (typed) catch blocks, you should have a good reason not to have a general catch-block additionally (as last of your specialised ones):

```
catch (System.Exception sysex)
        {      
            string msg = string.Format("Error number: {0} / Message: {1}", sysex.Number, sysex.Message);
            //Do something with this information!
        }
```

Or just

```
catch{throw;}
```

This depends on your needs and tools / habits of debugging...